# Inside HTML, URL remap library in python

Tags: python, html, url-rewriting, tornado

By URL remapping, I mean changing all the "href"s and "src"s and "action"s and ... inside an actual HTML doc.

Are there any python libraries to do this type of URL remapping?

On a python web server app (based on tornado) I want to be able to modify the HTML code that I server based on some conditions.

Imagine I read this HTMLs off disk but I need to replace all the links and ... to point to this subdomain/domain and path or that one.

Lets say I dont want to use templates to rewrite all the HTML that I have on disk (to put tags inside and replace the tags on run time) also lets for the sake of simplicity imagine I have no external links (like I never link to google.com [that requires conditional remapping]).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as i know, there is no such library, but you can use some html parsing library like [lxml](http://lxml.de/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) together with [`urlparse`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html) standard Python moule. I prefer using `lxml` and [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath).

For example, we have saved StackOverflow page as `doc.html`, and we want to do something with nodes which contains `href`, `src`, `actions`:

```
import urlparse

import lxml.html


with open('doc.htm') as f:
    doc = lxml.html.parse(f)

for el in doc.xpath('//*[@href | @src | @action]'):
    tag = el.tag
    href = el.get('href', '')
    if not href:
        continue

    # not really need to check for '/' when using urljoin, but this is just example
    if href.startswith('/'): 
        el.attrib['href'] = urlparse.urljoin('http://stackoverflow.com/', href)

# then get string representation of tree back
result = lxml.html.tostring(doc)
```

In this example, I'm only converting relative `href`'s started with '/' to absolute using `urlparse.urljoin`, and not all elements from XPath result used. But you can customize it for your needs.